# Combining where and having clauses in group by

Tags: soql, aggregate, group-by

I am running a group by query.  As part of this, I want to check the sum of one field, and then check if that sum exceeds a number.  The number itself depends on the value of a second field, which is a picklist field.  I can do this by using multiple queries, but I am trying to see if it can be done in one query.  Essentially, I want to be able to do something like this, which is not currently available in SOQL.

```
select fielda__c,sum(fieldb__c) from obja__c where 
(fieldc__c = 'Value A' and having sum(fieldb__c) > 10) or  
(fieldc__c = 'Value B' and having sum(fieldb__c) > 20) or
(fieldc__c = 'Value C' and having sum(fieldb__c) > 30) or
group by fielda__c
```

Is this possible, or is my only option to use multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured this out.  The key to this is that the HAVING Clause is used to apply a condition based *on a group field value*.  This means that we can do a filter in the having clause b*y including Field_C__c in the group fields*. This then gives me what I want i.e mix filter and aggregate fields.  This is what I came up with, and this works perfectly:

```
SELECT Field_A__c, Field_C__c,SUM(Field_B__c)
FROM My_Object__c
GROUP BY Field_A__c,Field_C__c
HAVING 
((SUM(Field_B__c) > 10 and Field_C__c = 'Value A') or
(SUM(Field_B__c) > 20 and Field_C__c = 'Value B') or
(SUM(Field_B__c) > 30 and Field_C__c = 'Value C'))
```

Kind of unorthodox, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Since `WHERE` clauses must go before `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` must go after, there is no way to combine them pairwise as you have. You need 3 separate queries all looking like:

```
SELECT Field_A__c, SUM(Field_B__c)
FROM My_Object__c
WHERE Field_C__c = 'Value A'
GROUP BY Field_A__c
HAVING SUM(Field_B__c) > 10
```